# Cassandra Eclipse Maven Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, cassandra

I would setup my eclipse maven project for cassandra, but I don't know what kind of archetype I've use. Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any archetypes to share, but here's a pom file you can use to get started. It has hadoop, pig and json dependencies you can get rid off if you like.  Since hector isn't in cassandra-all anymore, you have to add it separately.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.wakawaka</groupId>
  <artifactId>gore.access</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pig</groupId>
        <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.prettyprint</groupId>
        <artifactId>hector-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```